# query para sacar una cantidad por dos variables

Tags: sql

Estoy generando una query donde quiero saber la cantidad total de dos tipos de auditoria. Una que este dentro de la fecha que esta establecida para hacer y otra que se realizo antes de la fecha que se tenia que hacer.

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN Gage_Status = 'En calibracion' and Add_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and GETDATE())

from Quality_v_Gage_Record
WHERE Gage_Record_Type = 'Calibration' and Gage_Status = 'En calibracion'
```

donde `Gage_Status` es el estado que toma la auditoria al momento de que se esta realizando y Add_Date es la fecha que se esta generando también tengo el campo Description que es la fecha que se programo la auditoria

Comment: Y cual es tu pregunta en tu case when no lo veo completo faltaria el then 1 else 0

Comment: no lo tengo compreto por que no me regresa un error entonces estoy revisando si puedo sacarlo con un SUM

Comment: Y cual es el error que tienes para analizarlo

Comment: select SUM(CASE WHEN Gage_Status = 'En calibracion' and Add_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

from Quality_v_Gage_Record
WHERE Gage_Record_Type = 'Calibration' and Gage_Status = 'En calibracion'